# Remove a specific woocommerce registration errors

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, registration, woocommerce-subscriptions, filter-woocommerce

I'm trying to remove this registration error 'registration-error-email-exists' from woocommerce/wp error. Tried several options but couldn't figure out the solution. So any solutions without editing the wc core plugin file would be appriciated(as by editing the core plugin file a little solves my issue but I want to a proper solution).

So far I've tried

```
function wp_kama_woocommerce_registration_errors_filter( $errors, $email ){
        
    $errors = $errors->remove('registration-error-email-exists');
    return $errors;
        
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_errors', 'wp_kama_woocommerce_registration_errors_filter', 10, 4 );
```

But it seems not working, below are the reference I've followed so far
[Ref 1](https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/hook/woocommerce_registration_errors)
[Ref 2](https://wp-kama.com/function/WP_Error::remove)

Related woocommerce file: woocommerce/includes/wc-user-functions.php

Comment: `registration-error-email-exists` is not the part of `woocommerce_registration_errors` filter hook errors. you'll have to modify the core file or plugin to remove that specific error validation.

Comment: thanks, is there any way to do it without the core file modification?